# Automatic deployment of Docker containers on AWS ECS using Jenkins or Job Scheduler

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, continuous-integration, amazon-ecs

Currently we build our Docker containers and publish them to Amazon ECR. We have created TaskDefinitions and are able to deploy them manually on an ECS Cluster. So a new deployment involves manual update of the TaskDefinition.

Now we would like to automate the deployment so when a Docker Image is successfully build using Jenkins and published to the ECR repo we would like to replace the current running version with the newly build one.

Next to this we would like to give people the opportunity to launch a specific version of 1 or more combinations of docker containers. Any suggestion on how we could implement a continuous cycle without manually updating the TaskDefinitions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[This article](https://blogs.aws.amazon.com/application-management/post/Tx32RHFZHXY6ME1/Set-up-a-build-pipeline-with-Jenkins-and-Amazon-ECS) describes how to do Continuous deployments to ECS with Jenkins. It uses a shell script after the image has been built and pushed to update an ECS service with a new task definition revision. Hope it helps.

Comment: over two years past after the article written, no new way to do this?

Answer (score 9):

A more simple solution for this might be to use the ecs-deploy script from here:

https://github.com/silinternational/ecs-deploy

After my container has been built and deployed to dockerhub it's simply a matter of:

```
ecs-deploy -k $AWS_KEY -s $AWS_SECRET -r $AWS_REGION -c $CLUSTER_NAME -n $SERVICE_NAME -i $DOCKER_IMAGE_NAME
```

and that does it.

Comment: This was more useful than the article linked in the Answer, which would throw errors for me when trying to use the generated JSON file.  Note to future readers: ecs-deploy only updates 1 container of a Task Definition, so if you have multiple containers, you'll need to either run it multiple times with different args, or use another solution.

Comment: how to install aws-cli in VSTS powershell?